# Where can I find a navigation database for Brisbane?

Tags: navigation, datasets, australia

Does anyone know of a database that details the GPS locations of beacons within Brisbane; or a data-set that tells me air routes and associated en-route beacons, way points etc.?

I'd like to be able to plot a course on a map (Google, Bing, etc) from A to B given an air route or flight plan. SkyVector looks very similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: have you checked out apps like [foreflight](foreflight.com) or [Flight Plan](https://www.fltplan.com/) they may have what you are looking for

Comment: SkyVector already gives you GPS coordinates for every waypoint on your route in the PDF (click on "Nav Log"). Do you need anything additional?

Comment: "SkyVector looks very similar to what I'm trying to achieve." To make it easier to answer your question, please explain what you need that Skyvector does not already offer

Comment: I'm capturing ads-b messages once I receive an identification message I call the flightaware ap to retrieve the flight data. Within this satanic is the filed flight plan. Is need a database that holds the GPS coordinates of the relevant navigation beacons and presumably the way points of the airway the aircraft is one.

Comment: I'm trying to plot these points on my a map so I can track the aircraft. Ultimately the aircraft position to the filed flight plan will feed a machine learning model to accommodate ATC changes to the plan. Hope that makes sense.